# XSL how to calculate the sum of the product of the attribute values of each element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i have this xml

```
<Process>
    <name>name1</name>
    <ListOfItems>
        <item name="name2" price="10" quantity="1" value=""></item>
        <item name="name7" price="10" quantity="2" value=""></item>
        <item name="name12" price="10" quantity="3" value=""></item>
        <item name="name17" price="10" quantity="4" value=""></item>
    </ListOfItems>
    <taxType>TEN</taxType>
</Process>
```

and i want an output of

```
<ProcessResponse>
    <name>name1</name>
    <ListOfItems>
        <item name="name2" price="10" quantity="1" value="10"></item>
        <item name="name7" price="10" quantity="2" value="20"></item>
        <item name="name12" price="10" quantity="3" value="30"></item>
        <item name="name17" price="10" quantity="4" value="40"></item>
    </ListOfItems>
    <totalAmount>100</totalAmount>
    <taxAmount>10</taxAmount>
    <grandTotal>110</grandTotal>
</ProcessResponse>
```

its an invoice purpose, some extra info :

- value is the item cost (price x quantity)
- totalAmount is sum(value)
- taxAmount is (if taxType = AAA, taxAmount = totalAmount x (some fixed number / 100) )
- finally grandTotal = totalAmount + taxAmount
- GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 11.1.1.6.0(build 111214.0600.1553)
- stylesheet version="1.0"

i've done so much of research since 2 days and used some templates
to get the totalAmount but it worked on browser tester but not in the "jdeveloper" transformation.
and i fount the problem is at template match

in browser `<xsl:template match="/Process/ListOfItems">` worked but not in jdev
even the `<xsl:template match="/">` not works

please help to solve this problem,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: As various people indicate, the solution is completely different for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, so you really ought to save people's time by saying which version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `XSLT 2.0` it would be a lot easier to calculate the `sum()` of the values, but within `XSLT 1.0` it is a bit tricky, see next XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Rename root node -->
    <xsl:template match="Process">
        <ProcessResponse>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </ProcessResponse>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match on ListOfItems, to add new elements after it -->
    <xsl:template match="ListOfItems">
        <!-- Copy existing -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>

        <!-- Create the new elements -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]" mode="sumValue" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match on item element to do the calculation of value attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Copy existing attributes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

            <!-- Actual calculation -->
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@quantity * @price" />
            </xsl:attribute>

            <!-- Copy rest of nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="sumValue">
        <xsl:param name="currentSumValue" select="0" />

        <!-- Variable to store the updated sum value -->
        <xsl:variable name="updatedSumValue" select="$currentSumValue + (@quantity * @price)" />

        <!-- Proceed summing with the next item-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item[1]" mode="sumValue">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentSumValue" select="$updatedSumValue" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <!-- No more items. Summing is complete, we can display the totalAmount and calculate the rest -->
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::item)">
            <totalAmount><xsl:value-of select="$updatedSumValue"/></totalAmount>

            <!-- taxAmount -->
            <xsl:variable name="taxAmount">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="/Process/taxType = 'TEN'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$updatedSumValue * (10 div 100)" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$updatedSumValue" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <taxAmount><xsl:value-of select="$taxAmount" /></taxAmount>

            <!-- grandTotal -->
            <grandTotal><xsl:value-of select="$updatedSumValue + $taxAmount" /></grandTotal>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove element taxType -->
    <xsl:template match="taxType" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your input XML, the result would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessResponse>
    <name>name1</name>
    <ListOfItems>
        <item name="name2" price="10" quantity="1" value="10"/>
        <item name="name7" price="10" quantity="2" value="20"/>
        <item name="name12" price="10" quantity="3" value="30"/>
        <item name="name17" price="10" quantity="4" value="40"/>
    </ListOfItems>
    <totalAmount>100</totalAmount>
    <taxAmount>10</taxAmount>
    <grandTotal>110</grandTotal>
</ProcessResponse>
```

Hope it helps and that the comments in de XSLT help you on your way...

Answer (score 1):

Another version using XSLT 1.0, but it uses an extension function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ext"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="tmpvalue">
    <xsl:for-each select="//item">
        <value><xsl:value-of select="@price*@quantity"/></value>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="taxAmount">
    <!-- set you tax formula here -->
    <xsl:value-of select="'10'"/>
</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="Process">
        <ProcessResponse>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <totalAmount>
                <xsl:variable name="myValue" select="ext:node-set($tmpvalue)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($myValue/value)"/>
            </totalAmount>
            <taxAmount><xsl:value-of select="$taxAmount"/></taxAmount>
            <grandTotal>
                <xsl:variable name="myValue" select="ext:node-set($tmpvalue)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($myValue/value) + $taxAmount"/>
            </grandTotal>
        </ProcessResponse>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@price*@quantity"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also use the EXSLT node-set() function, only with less templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="taxRate" select=".06"/>

<xsl:template match="/Process">
    <ProcessResponse>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
        <!-- pre-process items -->
        <xsl:variable name="items">
            <xsl:for-each select="ListOfItems/item">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@price*@quantity" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="total" select="sum(exsl:node-set($items)/item/@value)" />
        <!-- output -->
        <ListOfItems>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$items"/>
        </ListOfItems>
        <totalAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
        </totalAmount>
        <taxAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total * $taxRate" />
        </taxAmount>
        <grandTotal>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total * (1 + $taxRate)" />
        </grandTotal>
    </ProcessResponse>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If your processor happens to support the EXSLT [dyn:map()](http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/map/index.html) extension function, then you have another way to get the expected result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="taxRate" select=".06"/>

<xsl:template match="/Process">
    <ProcessResponse>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
        <ListOfItems>
            <xsl:for-each select="ListOfItems/item">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@price * @quantity" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ListOfItems>
        <xsl:variable name="total" select="sum(dyn:map(ListOfItems/item, '@price * @quantity'))" />
        <total>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
        </total>
        <tax>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total * $taxRate" />
        </tax>
        <grandTotal>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total * (1 + $taxRate)" />
        </grandTotal>
    </ProcessResponse>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you are only interested in the total value and do not need to process the line items, then you can do without any extensions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="taxRate" select=".06"/>

<xsl:template match="/Process">
    <ProcessResponse>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name | ListOfItems"/>
        <xsl:variable name="total">
            <xsl:call-template name="process-items">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="ListOfItems/item"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <total>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
        </total>
        <tax>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total * $taxRate" />
        </tax>
        <grandTotal>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total * (1 + $taxRate)" />
        </grandTotal>
    </ProcessResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-items">
    <xsl:param name="items"/>
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$items">
            <xsl:variable name="item" select="$items[1]" />
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="process-items">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$total + $item/@price * $item/@quantity"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result here will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessResponse>
  <name>name1</name>
  <ListOfItems>
        <item name="name2" price="10" quantity="1" value=""/>
        <item name="name7" price="10" quantity="2" value=""/>
        <item name="name12" price="10" quantity="3" value=""/>
        <item name="name17" price="10" quantity="4" value=""/>
    </ListOfItems>
  <total>100</total>
  <tax>6</tax>
  <grandTotal>106</grandTotal>
</ProcessResponse>
```